# How to set JVM HEAP size per application in mule 3.7

Tags: mule

I need to deploy multiple application in single mule instance. i need to set JVM HEAP size as per application.

Please let me know how I can set the same.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to set for per application in mule. But if you want set for mule server then you change below properties available in Mule_HOME\conf\wrapper.conf

```
# Initial Java Heap Size (in MB)
wrapper.java.initmemory=512
# Maximum Java Heap Size (in MB)
wrapper.java.maxmemory=1024
```